# I am creating API from backend spring boot for drop down makeAndModel list of vehicle stuck in problem

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

I just creating the new feature in my app to make a drop down list for vehicle makeAndModel and checking the output by using postman but it does not showing output

java spring boot

```
this is my ApiController

@ApiOperation(value = "Get details of makeAndModel for vehicle")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/vehicle/make-and-model", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getMakeAndModel(@RequestParam("id") Map makeAndModelId) {
        try {
            return vehicleServiceImpl.getMakeAndModel(makeAndModelId);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("/vehicle/make-and-model===>>>", e);
            ErrorResponse errorResponse = new ErrorResponse(ErrorCodes.GENERAL_104.getKey(),
                    ErrorCodes.GENERAL_104.getValue());
            return StringUtility.convertOjectToJson(errorResponse);
        }

this is my makeAndModelRepository


public interface MakeAndModelRepository extends JpaRepository<VehicleMakeModel, Integer> {
    // List<VehicleMakeModel> findAll(String details, Integer id);
}
```

postman output

```
{
    "timestamp": "2019-05-21T12:57:17.205+0000",
    "status": 400,
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "message": "Required Map parameter 'id' is not present",
    "path": "/vehicle/make-and-model"
}
```

Comment: Hi Tejas. Could you show the postman request or the "curl" request? (I want to see how you're calling your operation)

Comment: You specify that the `makeAndModelId` is passed as a `@RequestParam` named `id`. That means your request URL needs to look something like `vehicle/make-and-model?id=1`.

Comment: yes sir can u please share u r id to elaboarete the issue #MARTIN

Comment: `@RequestMapping(value = "/vehicle/make-and-model/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)`